# UI5 Change table cell value acording to an input value

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I have a table inside an XML UI5 view. This table contains 3 columns, an input and two NumericContent. The value of the second NumericContent is the sum of the input and the first NumericContent. I expected this value to be updated automatically each time I change the input value, but unfortunately it didn't happen. Is there a solution for this to be done automatically ? Or I have to do this in the controller?

Thanks in advance.

```
... 
<items>
    <ColumnListItem counter="0" id="item1">
        <cells>
            <Input value="{Commitments}"></Input>               
            <NumericContent id="num1" value="{ResultPercent}"> </NumericContent>
            <NumericContent id="num2" value="{= ${Commitments} + ${ResultPercent}}"> </NumericContent>
        </cells>
    </ColumnListItem>
</items>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call

```
oModel.refresh(true);
```

This updates your model and refreshes your Control.

Comment: Call it as a callback of the input change ?

Comment: Call it in the submit event of the Input field.

Comment: Didn't work. This is my code:                                                                                          var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
oModel.refresh(true);

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two-way binding activated for this to work. Check you OData/json model's properties.

Comment: It is already the case: oModel.setDefaultBindingMode("TwoWay"); But, still don't work.